# compare-object excluding files older than x amount of time

Tags: powershell

I am using a powershell script to move files from 1 location to another then I'm using `compare-object` to get a hash value from both locations and signal if there is a problem.

As the `get-hash` takes a long time (speaking of multiple gb of data) I'd like to exclude files that are present already for hours/days.

my code:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (dir $nas_smb_share -Recurse | Where-Object{!$_.psiscontainer} | get-hash) -differenceObject (dir $cs_dest -Recurse | Where-Object  {!$_.psiscontainer} | get-hash) |
%{if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" ){$result = ("$($_.InputObject)")}}
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($result)){$res = "Transfer succeeded without problems"}
else {$res = ("transfer failed on following file(s): "+ (dir $cs_dest -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.psiscontainer } | get-hash | ? {$_.hashstring -match $result}) )}
```

The output is a mail with the files hash value that is changed.

So I'd like some input on how to change this part:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (dir $nas_smb_share -Recurse | Where-object{!$_.psiscontainer} | get-hash)
```

so it only takes files/folders that are not older than for example 1 hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EBGreen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45193934/45375) provides an effective solution to your filter-by-last-modified-time problem.

Let me complement it with a more efficient, streamlined version of your code that also addresses a conceptual problem with your `Compare-Object` call.

Note: Requires **PSv4+**, due to use of `Get-FileHash` (v4+) and `Get-ChildItem -File` (v3+) and the [simplified `Where-Object` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) (v3+).

```
# Get current time stamp.
$now = Get-Date
# Determine the cut-off time span.
$ts = New-TimeSpan -Hours 1

# Construct the filtering script block to pass to Where-Object below,
# which filters in only those files whose last-modified time is equal to
# or less than the time span.
$sb = { $now - $_.LastWriteTime -le $ts }
    
# Compare the file hashes and return those that are different on the right side.
# * Note the use of -File to limit Get-ChildItem's output to files.
# * Note the use of -Property Hash to ensure that the actual hash values are
#   compared - without it, Compare-Object would simply compare the results of
#   calling .ToString() on the input objects, which would yield the static 
#   'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileHashInfo' string value, and no differences
#   would ever be found.
# * Since we do want access to the .Path property of the
#  [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileHashInfo] objects output Get-FileHash
#  later, we must use -PassTru - otherwise, we'd get a 
#  [pscustomobject] with a .SideIndicator property and *only* a .Hash property.
# Note that even though the original objects are passed through
# with -PassThru, they are still *decorated* with a .SideIndicator property.
$result = Compare-Object -PassThru -Property Hash `
  (Get-ChildItem $nas_smb_share -File -Recurse | Where-Object $sb | Get-FileHash) `
  (Get-ChildItem $cs_dest -File -Recurse | Get-FileHash) |
    Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>'

# The [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileHashInfo] instances output by Get-FileHash
# have a .Path property containing the input file's full filename.
# Applying .Path to the $result as a whole will retrieve an array of the hashes'
# input filenames and, in a string context, concatenate them with spaces.
if ($result.Count -eq 0) {$res = "Transfer succeeded without problems"}
else                     {$res = "Transfer failed on following file(s): " + $result.Path }

# Output result.
$res
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter in your where clause:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (dir $nas_smb_share -Recurse | Where-object{(!$_.psiscontainer) -AND ($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1))} | get-hash)
```